# How to use CruiseControl.NET for database and windows service deployment?

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I have a VS 2008 solutions that includes a number of projects including a couple of class libraries, a web application, a windows service and a SQL 2008 database project. The build server currently has CruiseControl.NET version 1.5.0.6237, command-line subversion client and .NET framework 3.5 SP1 installed (Windows Server 2008 R2, no Visual Studio). I was able to configure ccnet to retrieve get latest from svn repository, build the solution using an MSBuild task and deploy the web application using robocopy. Now I'm struggling to make ccnet deploy the database script and I also need get the windows service deploy and start on the build/dev server. The latest error is that the assembly Microsoft.Data.Schema.Tasks is missing on the build server (I had to add Microsoft.Data.Schema.Common.targets and Microsoft.Data.Schema.SqlTasks.targets files to the solution and modify the database project file to get this far).

What would be the best CI/deployment approach in my scenario? Am I using the right tools for the job, or should I be using something other than ccnet? Do I need to install anything else on the build/dev server to make my life easier?

Please be very specific since I'm new to CruiseControl.NET and MSBuild tasks.

Comment: We use sqlps to deploy sql scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [nant](http://nant.sourceforge.net/).

- For a jump start you can use
  [nantbuilder](http://www.polestarsoft.com/products/nantbuilder/).
- For service install
  read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416872/install-uninstall-a-windows-service-in-a-build-script-with-nant)
- For a DB deploy read [this](http://hallertech.com/nant/index.html#database)

Comment: I was hoping not to use any additional tools but will have a look at nant.

Comment: I know what you mean, but you'l find nant lightweight & useful for more then just build server - developers will start to use this automated build, test & deploy process on their machine.