# Install/Uninstall a Windows Service in a build script with NAnt

Tags: windows, windows-services, build-automation, nant, installutil

Does NAnt have the ability to install or uninstall a windows service, using the InstallUtil utility or whatever else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call Nant's [exec](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/exec.html) task to call InstallUtil and can pass parameters to install or uninstall a service easily

```
 <target name="install-service">
    <exec program="${framework::get-framework-directory('net-2.0')}\InstallUtil.exe">
      <arg value="-i" />
      <arg value="/name=V1" />
      <arg value="C:\Service\SomeService.exe" />      
    </exec>
  </target>
```

Comment: instead of hard-linking to the path of installutil.exe, you should use the nant functions to get the path of the framework first: framework::get-framework-directory('net-2.0'): http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/functions/framework.get-framework-directory(System.String).html

Answer (score 1):

Nant or MSBuild? What's the problem with just running installutil yourself - that's what you'd do in MSBuild. (In general, builds dont do the installs for things like this as rule as typically your build should be able to run on a random build server).

Another option, which would take installutil out of the equation is [adding a self-install option to your service like this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/kim/archive/2009/01/04/self-installing-windows-service.aspx) (have a search for more by looking for `self install windows service`)

Comment: NAnt, sorry for the confusion with the tags.

Comment: I have a more complicated process that runs outside of the service, so I would like to leverage everything with NAnt.

Comment: @Brian: Cool (I subscribe to the msbuild tag - Sticking on a build-automation tag. In general installutil isnt a bad approach (though [the bootstrapping issues with it](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/4/19/Managed-Code-CustomActions-no-support-on-the-way-and-heres) are definitely important to be aware of

Answer (score 1):

If your service can be installed at different places, you can also uninstall it through its name using SC.EXE, as follows:

```
<property name="serviceName" value="Name of the service"/>
<exec program="sc" failonerror="false" verbose="true" if="${service::is-installed(serviceName,'.')}">
 <arg value="delete"/>
 <arg value="${serviceName}"/>
</exec>
```

Comment: service::is-installed required nant-contrib - http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/functions/service.is-installed.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [TopShelf Project](http://topshelf-project.com/) in your application to host your services, you can get command-line based tools for installing / removing the services without needing InstallUtil.

ServiceName.exe service install
ServiceName.exe service uninstall

And you can run the service directly and get a nice console window that you can CTRL+C to stop.  You can integrate this directly into nant or msbuild by executing the program.

Comment: I have a more complicated process than that, which is why I am using NAnt to consolidate...

Comment: If you just need something that will call InstallUtil on your services, then I recommend going with mcaaltuntas's answer.  You can even wrap it in a <foreach> in nant that will iterate on all the .exe's or all the services and install it all for you.